# Extracting a subtree from a BST in C++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I'm working on a C++ assignment. The project consists in building a template class for a Binary Search Tree.

So far, I've implemented fundamentals methods and iterators, and everything seems to work just fine. I now have to implement a method `subtree(const T &value)` that, given the target `value`, returns the tree with `value` as its root.

So far, I've defined this:

```
binarySearchTree subtree(const T &target) {

        nodo* node = findValue(target);

        binarySearchTree<T> newTree;
        newTree._root = node;

        return newTree;
}
```

where `findValue` is:

```
nodo* findValue(const T &target){

        if(_root -> value == target) {              
            return _root;
        } 
        else
            return findValueHelper(_root, target);
}
```

and `findValueHelper` is:

```
nodo* findValueHelper(nodo *ptr, const T &val) const {

        if (ptr == NULL)
            return NULL;
        if (val < ptr -> value)
            return findValueHelper(ptr -> left, val);
        else if (val > ptr -> value)
            return findValueHelper(ptr -> right, val);
        else 
            return ptr;

    }
```

and `nodo` is just my struct with a `T value`, a `left` and `right` pointer.

Now to the problem:

The extracted subtree is the right one, but after I print it I get a `segmentation fault` error, despite all of the elements are displayed correctly.

In the `main` I'm calling:

```
binarySearchTree<int> sub = t.subtree(2);
std::cout << sub << std::endl;
```

And I obviously redefined both `operator=` and `operator<<`.

Comment: Do you set left and right to NULL in the node constructor? Are you sure it's the `subtree` function that is causing the problem and not the printing function?

Comment: @Qubit printing function works fine, I've tested it over "normally-constructed" trees. And yes, left and right are set to NULL in the constructor.

Comment: Then what the answer suggests is probably the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't post all of your implementation this is a guess but probably right.

`newTree._root = node;` copies the pointer to the node. Now you have one node used in two trees. But the destructor of a tree probably frees the nodes. So when one tree goes out of scope (e.g. at the end of the function) the nodes a freed and the pointer becomes invalid. Next time something gets allocated your nodes get overwritten. So the printing still works (while being undefined behavior) but then your tree gets corrupted.

Comment: yeah, this makes sense! should I build a new node and use that one?

Comment: If you do that, you'll have to make a deep copy of the entire subtree. I suppose it really depends on what you want to do with this subtree, if it's something temporary you can simply set its root to NULL once you're done (and make sure the destructor doesn't try to free that) to avoid double freeing the data.

Comment: yes it's absolutely temporary, I just need to extract it and print it, basically. I think that worked, I defined a emptyRoot method that just sets the root to NULL and I don't get the sigsev error anymore. Thanks!